# How to store a key with multiple values in HashTable?

Tags: java, algorithm

Given two arrays of integers(for example) `X = [1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7]` and `Y = [1, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8]` to find the number of occurances of the highest appearing fraction where fraction is in the form of `X[i]/Y[i]` is a problem which we can solve using a HashTable to avoid `O(N^2)` complexity.

How do I insert entries `(key, value)` where key may contain multiple values? If I declare a class `Fraction` then the reference will be hashed and it won't work. The workaround that I used was to represent the fraction as a string `X[i]` concatanated with `Y[i]` but I am wondering if there's a better way to do this.

```java
    static int maximumOccuringFraction(int[] X, int[] Y) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int res = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < Y.length; i++) {
            int n = X[i];
            int d = Y[i];

            String s = String.valueOf(n) + String.valueOf(d);

            if(freq.containsKey(s)) {
                res = Math.max(res, freq.get(s) + 1);
                freq.put(s, freq.get(s) + 1);
            }
            else {
                freq.put(s, 1);
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps, keep values as lists.

Comment: @Amin How would that work considering I need to store the fraction with the number of times that it occurs?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you have multiple values per key. If the key contains multiple values, Defining class `Fraction` would and implementing `hashCode` and `equals` should do the job.

Comment: Would you consider `1/7` a different fraction than `2/14` ?

Comment: @c0der No, I prepare them first by dividing by the gcd so they are all in reduced forms.

Comment: In this case, `Double.hashCode((double)1/7)` might work for you. You'll need to store some info for unhashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a fraction class that overrides equals and hashcode

Here's what you can do:

```
public class Fraction {
  int numerator, denominator;
  public equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Fraction) {
      Fraction f = (Fraction) o;
      return f.numerator == numerator && f.denominator == denominator;
    }
    return false;
  }
  public int hashCode() {
    return numerator * denominator * denominator;
  }

}
```

Now use this Fraction class in your Map

Comment: Why is it returning `numerator * denominator * denominator` and what's the difference between that and `Objects.hash(numerator, denominator)` which is the default implementation that IntelliJ provides?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `numerator * denominator * denominator`  produces different values to `1/7` and `2/14`